# HTML Python Requests Library - Too Slow

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python requests library to get the source code for URL and apply a regex to extract some data using the following code:

```
for url in urls:
    print url
    page = requests.get(url)
    matches = re.findall('btn btn-primary font-bold">\s*<span>([^<]*)', page.text)
    for match in matches:
        print match
```

This code works but it is far too slow; it takes more than 5 seconds per request. Are there any suggestions to make it faster?

Also - should I be adding any try/error code for robustness?

Comment: Have you measured what is actually slow? How long does it take to get page content with curl? How long does this regex take to run?

Comment: And why are you using regular expressions to parse HTML? Why not use BeautifulSoup, for example?

Comment: you can use the python cProfile module to see where most time is spent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above speed profiling is a great way to see what is slowing you down. If this is an option, one obvious way to speed up the code is to parallelise it. Here is a simple suggestion

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as Threadpool
import requests
import re


def parallelURL(url):
    print url
    page = requests.get(url)
    matches = re.findall('btn btn-primary font-bold">\s*<span>([^<]*)', page.text)
    for match in matches:
       print match

pool = Threadpool(6)  #play around with this number depends on processor

pool.map(parallelURL,urlList)
```

On my computer this speeds up accessing google 10 times from 1.9s to 0.3s.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that for larger file downloads, getting the body in chunks is much faster. By default, I think `get(uri, stream=False)` uses a chunk size of 1.

```
import StringIO, requests

# Get the HTTP header
r = requests.get(uri, stream=True)
# Read the body in 1KB chunks
http_body_str = StringIO.StringIO()
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    http_body_str.write(chunk)
http_body = http_body_str.getvalue()
http_body_str.close()
```

For binary data I think you can use `io.BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`.